# Block an Order Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I am looking for a script that will block or remove an order button to prevent customers from double or triple ordering but clicking the button more then once. I don't know what something like this would be called. But the site was developed in Classic .asp. However I'm going to guess and say this would be javascript or jquery on an image button? Any suggestion or points for this would be a big help!!!!

Thanks,

Comment: What if customers want to click the button more than once?

Comment: i think making the button disable is not a correct solution ,the better solution (i think) is to show the quantities of product on every click show the user will know how many thing he has selected

Comment: This question cannot be answered without showing code. Ideally, when the data is processed *on the server* data (that can be used as a flag/guard/check) will be persisted in the database so that multiple "submits" will be nullified (only the first one is honored). How this persistence occurs depends upon the current data model. Then it's a matter of how to display this to the user.

Comment: @RegisteredUser this is a membership site no quantities here just join once. But if it were it would be a good idea and it could still be implemented. But I would rather pull the button so they can't keep hitting it.

Comment: i think also making disable this by only jquery wont be more useful since if user refresh the page it again available to click so i think you need to store something either email or any information in database ,so in future you can make the button disable for them

Comment: I need to allow multiple accounts for those who want them using the same name, address, credit card info and different user names and passwords. However users are inpatient and keep clicking but only want 1 account end up with 3, 4 or more accounts.

Comment: @FrankG. Oh! It's for registration?! Not ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having seen your comment on ianpgall's answer, I think the best solution would be a server-side check of the customer's order.

When they click the button and submit the form, check to see if they have already added the product to their basket. If they have you can either choose not to add it again, or ask the user to confirm.

This allows users to click the button more than once if they want to, and also prevents adding the product erroneously if the user has javascript disabled.

Comment: That's a really bad race condition. I'm sure the processing for this is fast enough that it may not be a problem, but the fact that you're checking for an existing order by the customer definitely isn't guaranteed. A random hiccup (or whatever reason) in the server that causes longer processing may bypass this check.

Comment: Other problem with server side is if I were to check the db for an existing record it would work however I have clients that have multiple accounts with us using the same address, phone, contact name, etc... so if that were the case it would not allow them causing a problem. So I might just have to go with this button disable.

Comment: The fact that a request may come in, submitting an order, and then a duplicate comes in 1 second later. If you expect the 2 requests to complete in the same order, and any DB logic to work perfectly, then this logic is fine. But I wouldn't expect that

Comment: @FrankG. Assuming the site is some kind of shop, don't you have a basket feature? You'd only need to check the basket (which would be linked to the current session) rather than the database for all previous orders. If there is a limit on what a customer can order beyond a single session, you might want to update your question.

Comment: @ianpgall Ah, that makes sense. Learn something new everyday. But see my above comment; I don't think it would need a database query.

Comment: @SaladinAkara The site is a membership join now site. You fill out your info, credit card info and submit. Now your a member. However some members have more then one account and use all the same info except there user name and password. But I have clients that are hitting the submit in one order more then once causing more then one account. But they only wanted one. I can't block a member based on name, address and things like that through the db because of the multiple accounts. There is no basket it's a one time sign up. If you want another come back and reorder.

Comment: @SaladinAkara Yep, that's definitely safer, and it scopes it on a per session basis like the OP seems to want. It's still not perfect, as network connections may still cause this "problem". I think a combination of this and disabling the button would be the best solution.

Comment: @FrankG. A little off topic, but... If they want to order again, they need to make a brand new account? Without specifics, the salesman and businessman in me says the system needs a major redesign. More on topic, as ianpgall says, a combination of both our solutions will probably work just fine for you.

Comment: @SaladinAkara true, but that's how the client wanted it. Sad but there was a time where web developers/programmers had a say in how things were done and how the client listened to your expertise!! :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to "disabling" the button. For example:

```
<input type="button" id="button1" value="Submit" />

$("#button1").click(function () {
    this.disabled = true;
});
```

If you're using AJAX, you can disable the button when it's clicked, then remove the attribute when the AJAX completes.

UPDATE:

Just as a reminder, this will only work if the user has Javascript enabled. That's a pretty safe thing to expect, but I just wanted to let you know. If it's not enabled, I'm not sure how else to prevent multiple clicks, without enforcing the user to have Javascript enabled. If this is a serious problem, you may want to look into that.

Comment: I don't think an "ASP Classic" site is using AJAX .. could surprise me, though.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. If using your script above will that stop the user from ordering more then once and is there a working for a user to do so? I'm finding my clients must be clicking on the order but to many times and I end up having to give credits. I'm not using AJAX :(

Comment: @pst Haha very true, but I wanted to throw that in there. If it's a basic form, then I think the original "disabling" code would work

Comment: What's the big deal if the OP is using AJAX? I was simply adding the information just in case. It doesn't hurt

Comment: @FrankG. So when the button is clicked, it is disabled...meaning it cannot be physically clicked again until the form is sent to the server, processed, and the (new) page is returned. That's the best you can do with Javascript and the client side.

Comment: That will help but there are issues with that. Such as it wont stop a user hitting enter and not sure if it's universal either! But it will help!

Comment: @FrankG. Very true, I think the more appropriate client solution is what John is suggesting, on a form submit. That should be safer as well in case any client validation may prevent a form being submitted, and like you said - pressing enter.

Comment: So what if I did both. Disable the button and create a server side something where I store a variable and do an If Var Date/Time = Current date/time within say 30 seconds then fail the second attempt? Would something like this work?

Comment: @FrankG Where did you plan on storing this variable? ASP Session?

Comment: most likely yes or a cookie. But I think a session variable would be safer. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the submit button once it has been clicked, which will prevent this in most cases. There are so many ways of doing this in JavaScript and jQuery.

This is one simple example using jQuery. It will disable any SUBMIT buttons in a form once the form has been submitted, preventing the submit button being pressed again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(function(){ 
    $(this).find('input[type=submit]').attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
}); 
</script>
```

If you also want to protect against the user clicking back and submitting again then you need a different solution based on ASP sessions or cookies.